# What could cause a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type mismatch" in GAE Query?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two code snippets which I am trying to run on the development server of Google App Engine SDK v1.8.8 for Java.

The first:

```
return datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey(Kinds.Provider,provider_id));
```

works as expected and returns the Provider Entity from the Data Store.

But when I tried to change it to a projection Query so that it will return only

```
Filter filter=new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
                                  Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                                  KeyFactory.createKey(Kinds.Provider,provider_id));
Query q = new Query(Kinds.Provider)
            .setFilter(filter)
    .addProjection(new PropertyProjection("address", String.class))
        .addProjection(new PropertyProjection("last_modified", String.class));;
    }
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
log.info("query:" + q.toString());

Entity result = pq.asSingleEntity();
```

I am getting a the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type mismatch.
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.RawValue.asType(RawValue.java:61)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyProjection.getValue(PropertyProjection.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.createFromPb(EntityTranslator.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.processQueryResult(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:199)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureLoaded(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.nextList(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:110)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.LazyList.forceResolveToIndex(LazyList.java:93)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.LazyList.resolveToIndex(LazyList.java:73)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.LazyList.resolveToIndex(LazyList.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.LazyList.isEmpty(LazyList.java:260)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl.asSingleEntity(PreparedQueryImpl.java:74)
```

logging the querys .toString() yeilds:

```
SELECT last_modified, address FROM Provider WHERE __key__ = Provider(99)
```

Any Ideas on what might be the reason for this exception?

Comment: thanks for both comments. fixed the title and made the Q more specific.

Comment: No, it's looking good now. :)  Noise deleted..

Answer (score 3):

OK, Found It.

within the DB last_modified is actually a `Long` so it should have been

```
.addProjection(new PropertyProjection("last_modified", Long.class));
```

Thank you for listening and I hoe this might help someone in the future...